Refresh page very slow when the program is deployed and runs with IIS (fast via visual studio)
I am programming a blazor server site and I am trying to test it locally with IIS.
The site loads fast and runs fast but if I refresh the page it is extremeley slow.
I don't face the same problem when running the site via Visual Studio.
I saw that the pages that have this problem are the ones that load google maps api.
I dont know if it is related but it seems related to me.
I worked in order to not have any errors in the console from javascript code but the problem still exists.
What is the way to find the reason which causes the problem?

I used the performance tool of chrome and saw that the slow part is the Network request in refresh taking 2 minutes

When you're developing a Blazor Server application and testing it locally with IIS, and you encounter slow page refreshes, it can be due to several factors. Here are some common causes and potential solutions:

WebSocket Configuration
WebSockets: Blazor Server relies on SignalR, which uses WebSockets for communication between the client and server. If WebSockets are not properly configured or supported in your IIS setup, it could cause issues, especially on page refresh.
Solution: Ensure that WebSockets are enabled on IIS.

Open IIS Manager.
Go to the server level in the Connections panel.
Click on "Features View".
Double-click on "WebSocket Protocol".
Ensure that it is installed and enabled.


Static Files Caching
Caching: If the static files (e.g., CSS, JS) are not properly cached, the browser may be requesting them repeatedly on each refresh, which can slow down the page load.
Solution: Make sure that static file caching is properly configured in IIS. You can set the appropriate headers to cache static files.

App Pool Configuration
Application Pool Recycling: If the application pool is recycling too frequently, this can cause delays on page refreshes.
Solution: Check the recycling settings for your application pool.


Go to your application's pool in IIS Manager.
Click on "Advanced Settings".
Adjust the "Regular Time Interval" for recycling or disable it for development purposes.
